# Deleting Particular Parts of a JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Was hoping someone may be able to point me in the right direction with this.

I have returned a list object in JSON format from .Net and then parse with JQuery.

```
var jsonOpens = $g.parseJSON(seriesReturn);
```

If I alert this I then receive the following:

```
1326531600000,8,49,1326531600000,8,49,1326535200000,11,169,1326535200000,11,169
```

What I then need to do with this is remove the second column.

I managed to do that by looping through and deleting

```
  for (var i = 0; i < jsonOpens.length; i++) {                    
       delete jsonOpens[i] [1];                           
       }
```

This works but still leaves the column in place i.e alerts:

```
1326531600000,,49,1326531600000,,49,1326535200000,,169,1326535200000,,169
```

I tried doing a replace by replacing the double commas with single commas but this doesn't work in this format.

What would be the best way for me to identify a column and remove it completey whilst keeping the same format?

Comment: could you provide the actual json structure please? console.log it, dont alert

Comment: That looks more like an Array than JSON to me.

Comment: [["\/Date(1323849600000)\/",8,49],["\/Date(1323849600000)\/",8,49]]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming it's a JS array, you should be able to use the .splice() method to remove the appropriate elements:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp

So, your loop would be (I think)

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsonOpens.length; i++) {                    
   jsonOpens[i].splice(1,1);                           
 }
```

Comment: Using splice: jsonOpens[i].splice(1,1);

Comment: In loop should only be: jsonOpens[i].splice(1,1); This returns the deleted item and should not be assigned.

Comment: Worked perfectly, cheers guys. NOt sure if I should post this here or not but how would I get around removing the entire element of an array. I.e.  if(jsonClicks[i][1] == 0) {jsonClicks[i].splice(0, 3); This works but if I get consecutive 0's I end up with an array   (1326531600000,8,49,,,1326531600000,8,49,,,,1326535200000,11,169,1326535200000,11,169) where the removes have taken place.

Comment: Try using splice again, but at a level above. e.g. jsonClicks.splice(i,1) - not sure if this is spot on, but you get the idea?